# Trigonometric Identities

Tags: trigonometry

When I have an expression

$ 2 \cos^2x + 4 \sin^2x $

How do I simplify it ?

Why do I get -

$ 2-2\sin^2x + 4 \sin^2x $

I know that we have to use

$\sin^2x + \cos^2x = 1 $

But how do I remove 2 and 4 completely to apply that rule ?

Comment: This is because $\sin ^2x + \cos^2x=1$

Comment: @YujieZha oh yea I know it's that rule , but I'm not too sure how to manipulate it

Answer (score 4):

To go from $$2 \cos^2x + 4 \sin^2x$$
to $$2-2\sin^2x + 4 \sin^2x$$

You should recognize that there are no cosines in the result. The most natural way for this to occur would be the use of the identity $\sin ^2x + \cos^2x=1$, which can be rewritten as $$\cos^2x=1 - \sin ^2x$$

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify like the following:
 $$2\cos^2(x) + 4\sin^2(x) = 2(\sin^2(x) + \cos^2(x)) + 2\sin^2(x) = 2 + 2\sin^2(x) = 2(1+\sin^2(x)) = 3 - \cos(2x)$$

Also, in the last step I've used the following equation:
$$\sin^2(x) = \frac{1 - \cos(2 x)}{2}$$